# cache video content for offline iphone/ipad web apps in mobile safari (html5)?

Tags: iphone, ipad, caching, html5-video

i have seen a few (discouraging) questions related to this subject but I am still not clear on the answer.

is it possible to cache video content for immediate playback in an offline web app on the iphone or ipad?

(i believe that there is a 5mb limit for any cached file.)  can videos cache the same way other files can, using the manifest?  are there alternatives?

Comment: no, I have not.  I have not even built an offline web app yet, so I have some work cut out for me.  you neither?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment in IOS 5.1 you can't save video or audio files to Application Cache this is valid for the iPhone and for the iPad, but desktop safari can store and play offline video e and audio files since version 5.1 of the Safari browser.

This is probably a precaution to prevent consuming unnecessary network data (usually 3G data is limited and expensive), because every file declared in the manifest get's downloaded and cached even if the user doesn't visit the portion of the site having that content.

In my opinion if the users had the wifi enabled safari for ios should be able to cache video and audio files.